# Block proxy server clients from accessing local devices on the server

Tags: networking, proxy, namespaces, iptables, proxy-server

I'm running a public proxy server and would like to block clients from accessing local devices on the server.

Local devices are on `10.0.0.0/8`.

The proxy server runs on `127.0.0.1:31336`. Access to the proxy server is made by reverse proxy on `nginx` which is listening on a public IP address.

Would an `iptables` rule like "reject `127.0.0.1:31336` from accessing `10.0.0.0/8`" work? If so can I get an example `iptables` command to do so?

If not, would I have to work with network namespaces to achieve what I am seeking for?

Answer (score 0):

why would you even use iptables for blocking client of a nginx, anyway follow this tutorial it will show you how you can allow or deny an ip or range ip : https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-tcp/